# In SQLAlchemy, can you filter a polymorphically associated model by the type of its associated record?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, polymorphic-associations

I'm using a polymorphic association in SQLAlchemy as described in [this example](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2007/05/29/polymorphic-associations-with-sqlalchemy/).  It can also be found in the examples directory in the SQLAlchemy source code.

Given this setup, I want to query for all `Address`es that are associated with `User`s.  Not `a user` but `any user`.

In raw SQL, I could do that like this:

```
select addresses.* from addresses 
join address_associations 
on addresses.assoc_id = address_associations.assoc_id
where address_associations.type = 'user'
```

Is there a way to do this using the ORM Session?

Could I just run this raw SQL and then apply the Address class to each row in the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ad-hoc joins using the ORM are described at:

http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/tutorial.html#querying-with-joins

```
for address in sess.query(Address).join(Address.association).filter_by(type='users'):
    print "Street", address.street, "Member", address.member
```